# How to select specific fields on FaunaDB Query Language?

Tags: faunadb

I can't find anything about how to do this type of query in FaunaDB. I need to select only specifics fields from a document, not all fields. I can select one field using `Select` function, like below:

```
serverClient.query(
  q.Map(
    q.Paginate(q.Documents(q.Collection('products')), {
      size: 12,
    }),
    q.Lambda('X', q.Select(['data', 'title'], q.Get(q.Var('X'))))
  )
)
```

Forget the `selectAll` function, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also return an object literal like this:

```
serverClient.query(
  q.Map(
    q.Paginate(q.Documents(q.Collection('products')), {
      size: 12,
    }),
    q.Lambda(
     'X',
     {
       title: q.Select(['data', 'title'], q.Get(q.Var('X')),
       otherField: q.Select(['data', 'other'], q.Get(q.Var('X'))
     }
    )
  )
)
```

Also you are missing the end and beginning quotation marks in your question at `['data, title']`

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this would be to create an index that returns the values required. For example, if using the shell:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "<name of index>",
  source: Collection("products"),
  values: [
    { field: ["data", "title"] },
    { field: ["data", "<another field name>"] }
  ]
})
```

Then querying that index would return you the fields defined in the values of the index.

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(Index("<name of index>"))
  ),
  Lambda("product", Var("product"))
)
```

Although these examples are to be used in the shell, they can easily be used in code by adding a `q.` in front of each built-in function.

Comment: your solution appears to me more performative than the solution via select, right?

Comment: Hey, Brecht, Dev Advocate here. This solution is indeed slightly more performant and much cheaper than the solution with Select. Which option you want to use is a tradeoff.
Indexes can't be changed, you'll have to create a new index when a new field arrives that you want to add to your results. With Map/Get + Select you can just modify the query, done. So in essence it's a tradeoff between flexibility and performance/price. To be clear:

- Map/Get: 1 read for the index page, N reads for the gets (1 read = 1 get): N+1 reads
- Index values: 1 read for the index page